# Receiving logs from filebeat to ECK on GKE

Tags: elasticsearch, google-kubernetes-engine, filebeat

I built a cluster on GKE with ECK operator and am trying to send logs from an on premises [Filebeat](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/ElasticSearch/Filebeat) installation to the cloud.

Elasticsearch has LoadBlancer IP. I specified certificate, password and necessary things, but I couldn't make it work. Is there a tutorial?